# Backtrack 4 audio volume slider is not working

Tags: linux, audio, backtrack

I am using Backtrack 4 and loving it. But the one problem is the audio volume slider of the gnome notification bar is not working. Hence I have to depend on either that of VLC's audio volume slider or on the speaker's hardware.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The alsamixer is working nicely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on Backtrack 5 R3 and may work on Backtrack 4.

Go to System » Preferences » Startup Applications

Make sure you’re in the tab ‘Startup programs’. Click on "Add". Then enter the following

- Name:    Pulseaudio daemon
- Command: `/usr/bin/pulseaudio`
- Comment: Start the sound daemon

Now logout, then login again. It's normal that sound doesn't work on Ubuntu 10.04 under root.

Comment: Recently I have upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 and the slider is working in it.